# OpenCart - Show Manufacturer on Shopping Cart/Checkout page

Tags: php, opencart

OpenCart 1.5.6 & Default theme.

How can I display 'Manufacturer' on Shopping Cart page for every product added to cart (below product name)?

I have tried:

File: \catalog\controller\checkout\confirm.php

Added:

```
if ($this->config->get('config_manufacturer')) {
    $manufacturer = $product['manufacturer'];
} else {
    $manufacturer = false;
}
```

before:

```
$product_data[] = array(
```

and added:

```
'manufacturer'    => $product['manufacturer'],
```

after:

```
'model'      => $product['model'],
```

File: \catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\confirm.tpl

added:

```
<?php if ($product['manufacturer']) { ?>[<?php echo $product['manufacturer']; ?>]<?php } ?>
```

after:

```
<td class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a>
```

But showing error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: manufacturer in /x/x/x/x/catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php on line 254
```

Any clue?

Comment: I don't know why, but in OC 1.5.5.1 in `confirm.php` controller the products are processed **two times** but only once they are set to template variable, and this is closer to the end of the file. Look for `$this->data['products'] = array();` and check if Your manufacturer is added there in the following loop. But a hint though: the products are not loaded from DB but from session (`$this->cart->getProducts()`) and I am almost certain that the products loaded from session does not contain the manufacturer information...

Comment: Yes, no success with both options ...

Comment: According to the URL of my cart, it seems view/theme/default/template/checkout/cart.tpl should be modified.